# Await not working for 'Parse Xamarin Android'

Tags: c#, android, parsing, xamarin

I was trying to get Parse to work on Xamarin. I am building an android app on C#.
During the quick start guide, i was told to copy and paste this codes into Oncreate

```
var testObject = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
testObject ["foo"] = "bar";
await testObject.SaveAsync();
```

But it shows an error for 'await'
Does anyone knows why? Any help is greatly appreciated!

it was also stated that i need to mark the function as async. But i don't understand what it wants.
Note: You'll need to mark the function as async in order to await the result of the SaveAsync call

https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#android/xamarin/blank

Comment: Does the version of Xamarin you're using support `async`? Last time I checked it was in the opt-in prerelease (Beta) stage.

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: I'm not sure if this applies to Xamarin, correct me if I'm wrong.

Basically, what's wrong is that the function is not async. I'm guessing your function definition looks something like this:

```
public void MyFunction(MyObject arg, etc)
{
    var testObject = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
    testObject ["foo"] = "bar";
    await testObject.SaveAsync();
}
```

`await` was introduced later in the language, and to make sure that it didn't break any old code, you needed to add the `async` modifier to a method for it to be able to use `async`. Like this:

```
//note ▼▼▼▼▼ the async modifier in the function declaration
public async void MyFunction(MyObject arg, etc)
{
    var testObject = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
    testObject ["foo"] = "bar";
    await testObject.SaveAsync();
}
```

That will compile. However, there is another improvement you can do. You can use the `Task` class instead as a return value. That will let other methods use `await` on your method. Like this:

```
//note the   ▼▼▼▼ new return value
public async Task MyFunction(MyObject arg, etc)
{
    var testObject = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
    testObject ["foo"] = "bar";
    await testObject.SaveAsync();
}
```

This will mean other people will be able to do something like this:

```
await MyFunction(arguments);
```